# MongoDB not showing storage engine

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

Why does Mongo 3.2.6. not show a storage engine when calling db.serverStatus().storageEngine?

Reason for asking is to get more statistics for wiredTiger.

Comment: From v. 3.2 onwards, I presume WiredTiger is default storage engine.

Comment: Are you sure you're using MongoDB 3.2.6? My quick testing shows that `db.serverStatus().storageEngine` is still present. There's also `db.serverStatus().wiredTiger` for more WiredTiger info.

Comment: You can run 'db.version()' in the shell to confirm mongod version.

Comment: Yes:  
`mongos> db.version()
3.2.6`

Empty result:
`mongos> db.serverStatus().storageEngine
mongos>`

Comment: I'm having the same issue, db.serverStatus() doesnt show the storage engine